# Is there a general way to get the QR decomposition of a companion matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, matrix-decomposition, companion-matrices

Is there a general way to get the QR decomposition of a companion matrix? Is it considered a sparse matrix? Is shifting always required in this case?

Comment: A companion matrix is sparse, of course.  Are you asking about QR decomposition methods "tailored" to the case of a companion matrix?  This has been studied in the literature, e.g. in connection with finding roots of a polynomial.  Am I just repeating stuff you already know?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I do know that, but my problem is finding a QR implementation that actually works. Everyone and their mother online says "lol just use Numpy" but I want to actually perform the QR decomposition without external libraries.

Comment: QR decomposition $\neq$ QR algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 2007 paper by Chandrasekaran et al on a tailored QR decomposition for companion matrices:

[A Fast QR Algorithm for Companion Matrices](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~xiaj/work/companion.pdf)

The discussion there is about repeated QR iterates converging to a Schur form.  A single QR decomposition by itself is done there using what the authors call "sequentially semi-separable" (SSS) forms.

---

There are several notions of "companion matrix", each realizing the property of having a specified characteristic polynomial.  The version referred to in the comments below ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)) is called the Frobenius companion matrix:

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -c_0 \\
 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -c_1 \\
 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & -c_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} $$

having characteristic polynomial $p(t) = t^n + c_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1 t + c_0$.

With this convention it is trivial to express $C$, which is [upper Hessenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix), as the product $QR$ of an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and an upper triangular matrix $R$:

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \; \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -c_1 \\
 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & -c_{n-1} \\
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -c_0 \end{bmatrix} $$

It seems doubtful that this would be useful, but the $QR$ decomposition of a general matrix can be used for solving systems of equations "by elimination" in much the way that row-echelon form of an augmented matrix can be used.  The basic idea is to replace elementary row operations with orthogonal transformations (typically [Givens rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) or [Householder transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) acting on the rows of the matrix).

A less trivial $QR$ factorization would address a different form of companion matrix (also upper Hessenberg) used in the paper linked at top:

$$ PC^TP^T = \begin{bmatrix}
-c_{n-1} & -c_{n-2} & \ldots & -c_1 & -c_0 \\
 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix that reverses the ordering of rows:

$$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: I found that paper as well but it's way over my head.

Comment: What I want is to simply get the QR decomposition of a matrix. Every implementation I've found online has a problem with it somewhere.

Comment: So you want to input a companion matrix and get $C=QR $?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The kind shown at the top of this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Comment: It is trivial to factor that type of companion matrix as an orthogonal matrix times an upper triangular matrix, i.e. $QR$.

Comment: Just in case, here's the [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-7643-8539-2_7).